# Sed replace spaces and a character before end of line

Tags: text, sed, spaces

I have this line:

```
\\Server1\A Share & Test & Check    M
```

I want this output:

```
\\Server1\A Share & Test & Check
```

It should end with a character and not spaces (\\Server1\A Share & Test & Check)

I tried this:

```
 sed -i "s/[ *\t[a-z]]*$//I" shares.txt
```

It removes the last letter but not the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you are after is [`\s*[a-z]*$`](http://regex101.com/r/rM2bX5/1)

```
sed -i "s/\s*[a-z]*$//I" shares.txt
```

`\s` is for *any white space character*

Comment: IN you example last is in capital so include `A-Z` in regex

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo "\\Server1\A Share & Test & Check    M" | sed 's/[\tA-Za-z]*$//g'
```

output:

```
echo "\\Server1\A Share & Test & Check
```